# Print and Insert a static matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, static, segmentation-fault

I'd like to fill and print a static matrix, for sorting then with the Young Tablue proprieties [Here](https://lyle.smu.edu/~saad/courses/cse3358/ps5/problemset5sol.pdf), but I have a problem with some dimension (row and col) input, with some input show me the right matrix, but with others give me seg.fault or a weird output.
Here the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 32

void fill( int A[MAX][MAX], int numRig, int numCol, int numElem){
 int i,j; 
 int count = 0; 

 for ( i = 0 ; i < numRig; i++ ) {

     for ( j = 0 ; j < numCol; j++) {




             A[i][j] = rand() % 20;
            //fscanf(stdin,"%d", &A[i][j]);
             //DEBUG
             printf("%d\n", A[i][j]);

    }
 }

 }

void stamp(int A[MAX][MAX], int numRig, int numCol){
int k,h;

  for ( h = 0 ; h < numRig; h++ ) {

     for ( k = 0 ; k < numCol; k++) {


            printf("%d ", A[h][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 }
```

the main

```
 int main () {
   int row,col;
   printf("Insert row and col:\n");
   scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);
   int A[row][col];
   fill(A,row,col);
   stamp(A,row,col);
   return 0;
}
```

output with row=4 and col=4:
 "3 6 17 15 -1 0 0 0 2017675728 32765 -741456064 21906 
-1 0 0 0 2017675728 32765 -741456064 21906 0 0 -741454033 21906 
2017675728 32765 -741456064 21906 0 0 -741454033 21906 4 0 0 0 
0 0 -741454033 21906 4 0 0 0 2017675976 32765 2017675552 32765 
4 0 0 0 2017675976 32765 2017675552 32765 3 0 0 0 
2017675976 32765 2017675552 32765 3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 
"

I tried with dynamic allocation: 
     `a=(int**)malloc(row*(sizeof(int*)));
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    a[i]=(int*)malloc(col*sizeof(int));`

and all works fine, but I must use static allocation.

Comment: You SHOULD allocate your matrix before trying to use it, and this is done using at least int A[MAX][MAX] in your main

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: i allocate the matrix in this way: int row,col;
int A[row][col];
fill(A,row,col);
stamp(A,row,col);

Comment: `int row,col; int A[row][col];` row and col must be initialized before you declare the array. And this crap `a=(int**)malloc(row*(sizeof(int*)))` is not even an multi-dimensional array.

Comment: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: You have allocated a 1-dimensional array of pointers, with each element pointing to a 1-dimensional array of int. But your functions work on 2-dimensional arrays of int. They are not the same thing.

Comment: You could change your functions to use `int **A`, then it would work with your array of pointers to arrays of int.

Comment: I must use static allocation, with int **A all work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the address of `A[i][j]` is *by definition* `&A[0][0] + i * cols + j` where `cols` is the declared number of columns of the matrix.

So if you declare the matrix as `int A[4][4]` in the main, you only reserve memory for 16 ints. But as you use it as `int A[32][32]` in your functions address of `A[3][0]` is 60 places after `A[0][0]` so far beyond the allocated array => you just invoke Undefined Behaviour

You must declare the matrix in main as `int A[MAX][MAX];`, you can then safely only use first rows and first columns as long as the matrix is **declared** with same dimensions in main and all the functions.

---

Variable Length Array can also be a nice alternative here (thanks to Jonathan Leffler for suggesting this). They are supported in C99, and are optionally supported since C11, but all major recent C compilers accept it, even if MSVC support is fairly recent.

That means that you can still declare `int A[row][col];` in main, but your function declaration must become:

```
void fill( int numRig, int numCol, int A[numRig][numCol]){
...
}
void stamp(int numRig, int numCol, int A[numRig][numCol]){
...
}
```

The variable length array shall be declared **after** its dimension in the function declaration.

But now as the declared dimensions of the matrix are consistent throughout the program, no undefined behaviour is involved...

---

According to the standard anyway, simply aliasing a matrix or a simple array to a matrix or array of a different size **is** undefined behaviour.

Comment: There's an alternative fix; pass the size parameters to the function before the array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You are right, VLA is a nice alternative here provided using a not too old compiler...

Comment: So i can read and write by using this A[i][i*Col+i] with A[MAX][MAX]?
I'm using gcc on linux, so i think VLA it's avaiable, it isnt right?

Comment: @JimMinor9 Sorry by I cannot understand you last comment. I have given 2 possible ways, but none involve `A[i][i*Col+i]`...

Comment: For insert, it's okay, but when i want to print, the output is:
3 4 
5 6 
for a 3x3 matrix  and with printf("%d", A[0][0] + h * numCol + k);

Comment: @JimMinor9: if you use one of the 2 proposed way, you should use `A[i][j]` or `A[h][k]` for insert and print...